# Как поместить файл в ресурсы и достать его потом?

Tags: c#, .net

Мне требуется поместить в ресурсы файл (например, файл локальной базы данных или файл xml) **без необходимости его изменения** в рантайме.

Файл при этом должен быть зашит в бинарник.

Как это сделать, я знаю. Добавляю файл в проект, выбираю *действие при сборке - Resource* и *Копировать в выходной каталог - Не копировать*. Но как в коде достать его в Stream?

Comment: @Grundy, а мне что нужно было искать? Как достать из ресурсов текстовый файл? Но у меня не текстовый файл. Я бы назвал это не дубликатом, а обобщением

Comment: Тип файла не имеет значения: код в обоих ответах одинаков. Дубликаты как раз и призваны улучшить поиск вопросов с одинаковыми ответами

Comment: @Grundy, тогда я не понял, что мне делать с этой информацией "Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как прочитать txt-файл из ресурсов?"

Comment: Два варианта: согласиться что это дубликат (что ты уже сделал), либо можно было ничего не делать, и вопрос так и остался бы как есть, либо по результатам голосования его так же закрыли как дубликат, либо не закрыли

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для помещения в ресурс, необходимо выставить свойство Build Action в Embeded Resource.

Для того, что бы вытащить ресурс в поток, нужно указать его полное имя (Qualified Name) что включает в себя имя сборки и директории внутри проекта, если они есть. Например, сборка называется Project, а в ней есть директория Data, а в ней ресурс Resource.xml, следовательно, полное имя будет Project.Data.Resource.xml

Код

```
var path = "Project.Data.Resource.xml"
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(path)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Добовляете ресурс в проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и через код получаете доступ к ресурсу.

```
byte[] emptyDbBytes = Properties.Resources.empty;
var emptyDbStream = new MemoryStream(emptyDbBytes);
```

Comment: Или просто так: `var emptyDbStream = new MemoryStream((byte[])Properties.Resources.empty);`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы добавить файл в проект как внедренный ресурс, выполните следующие действия (для примера - текстовый файл и картинка).

1. Создайте новый проект. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по имени
   проекта, нажмите кнопку ***Добавить*** и выберите команду ***Добавить
   новый элемент***.

   2. В диалоговом окне ***Новый элемент*** меню
      выберите ***Текстовый файл*** и назовите файл MyTextFile.txt. Когда файл
      открывается в    IDE, добавьте текст, а затем    закройте файл.    Повторите шаги 1 и 2, чтобы
      добавить в проект, но вместо выбора Текстового файла с новым типом
      элемента растрового изображения,    выберите ***Файл точечного рисунка*** и
      измените имя на MyImage.bmp. При    открытии нового изображения в
      IDE,    нарисуйте что-нибудь , а затем закройте файл.
   3. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши
      на текстовом файле или точечном рисунке и выберите команду ***Свойства***. 
      В диалоговом окне свойств найдите свойство ***Действие при построении*** .
      По умолчанию это свойство имеет значение для    содержимого.
      Выберите свойство и измените свойство ***Действие*** при    построении
      значение ***Внедренный ресурс***.

Вот пример доступа через `Assembly`:

```
try   {
      _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      _imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyImage.bmp");
      _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyTextFile.txt"));
   }
   catch
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
   }
```

Comment: Попробовал на примере картинки, которая уже есть в ресурсах. `var stream = Application.ResourceAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("clock.png");`. stream == null в результате. Нэймспейс у картинки не задан

Comment: Возможно вы не так меня поняли. Файл находится не в Resources.resx

Comment: @iRumba Пробовали читать его по физическому пути расположения ?

Comment: 1. в свойствах ресурса нужно указать, что он `Embedded` (в свойстве `Build action`). 2. Путь нужно указывать полностью. Посмотреть путь можно через `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()`

Comment: @iRumba здесь подробно описан процесс по регистрации и доступу к ресурсам https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример. У вас не понятно что такое `objAssembly`, и что за ресурс `My.Namespace.empty.mdb`, откуда он взялся, как вы его добавили и тд.

Comment: @iRumba Сейчас попытаюсь развернуть свой ответ более подробно.